# TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for Sub: 'str' and 'int' on line 8

Tags: python, python-3.x

Why do I keep getting this answer?
**TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for Sub: 'str' and 'int' on line 8**

```
#Define payment, knowing that up to 40 hours it is normal rate, and above that every hour is paid at 150%.
totalHours = input("Enter the total amount of worked hours:\n")
hourlyWage = input("Enter the payrate per hour:\n")
if totalHours <= 40:
    regularHours = totalHours
    overtime = 0
else:
    overtime = float(input(totalHours - 40))
    regularHours = float(input(40))
payment = hourlyWage*regularHours + (1.5*hourlyWage)*overtime
print (payment)
```

Comment: not getting any error. Its working perfectly fine.

Comment: @AC The problem is related to the fact that the OP attempts to subtract a number (40) from a string (`totalHours`). The OP also probably does not know what to pass to `input()`, but that's a different problem.

Comment: Code is perfectly fine in Python 2.x, may be you are using Python 3.x

Comment: Many thanks to my question, it is helping me figuring it out. 

I am trying this as well, giving me an error in line 9, 


hrs = input("Enter Hours:\n")
rt = input("Enter Rate:\n")
if input (hrs <= (40)) :
    pay = (float(hrs)*float(rt))
    print (pay)
elif input (hrs > 40) :
    pay = (40*float(rt)+((float(rt)*1.5)*hrs-40)
print (pay)

Answer (score 0):

in python3, if you give input, it accepts it as string only. You need to convert it to int. Also, the input in the else part is unnecessary

```
#Define payment, knowing that up to 40 hours it is normal rate, and above that every hour is paid at 150%.
totalHours = int(input("Enter the total amount of worked hours:\n"))
hourlyWage = int(input("Enter the payrate per hour:\n"))
if totalHours <= 40:
    regularHours = totalHours
    overtime = 0
else:
    overtime = float(totalHours - 40)
    regularHours = float(40)
payment = hourlyWage*regularHours + (1.5*hourlyWage)*overtime
print (payment)
```

Comment: I just needed to float the input and then it worked fine. Thanks!!!!

Also, I tried my previous code with your instructions and it worked good too!

#pay 10.5 per hour up to 40 hours, 50% more above
hrs = float(input("Enter Hours:\n"))
rt = float(input("Enter Rate:\n"))
if hrs <= 40 :
    pay = (float(hrs)*float(rt))
elif hrs > 40 :
    pay = (40*rt)+((rt*1.5)*(hrs-40))
print (pay)


Again, many thanks!

Comment: Happy to help :D please Upvote if you found it useful

Answer (score 0):

You need to add `int` convertation.

```
totalHours = int(input("Enter the total amount of worked hours:\n"))
hourlyWage = int(input("Enter the payrate per hour:\n"))
```

As from `input` you get `str` and not `int` so you cant do math operations with `str` and `int`.